# How to reveal a folder in explorer from terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, files

I want to open corresponding folder in file explorer. I tried to get the command for that. For example, let's say my current terminal address is

```
dkp@DKP:~/Documents$
```

Now, i want to open Documents in file explorer, if there is any way or command to do so.

Reverse(and other) question :- I was also wondering if there is any short-cut key for `right-key -> open in terminal`. 

Thanks, peace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type

```
nautilus .
```

But I recommend

```
nautilus . 2>/dev/null & disown
```

so that you can continue to use the terminal and close it without auto-closing nautilus, and prevent any warnings printing in the terminal

`.` is the current working directory

You can also just open a terminal and type `nautilus Documents` from home or `nautilus ~/Documents` from anywhere

Comment: Is there any shortcut key for reverse action?

Comment: @DKP maybe you'll find something here [Keyboard shortcut for open terminal Nautilus >= 3.16](//askubuntu.com/q/680016)

Comment: it's a pleasure @DKP :)